# Python getting mean time interval in different entries of panda frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data (pandaframe) with time stamps, Now I want to get mean timeinterval between each entries. Getting it for any two consecutive entries but what is the best way to get the mean time interval between all entries.

```
     Polling Timestamp                MAC      
0    2016-11-10T02:04:00.000Z  00:04:56:CD:7D:17     
1    2016-11-10T02:09:00.000Z  00:04:56:CD:7D:17    
2    2016-11-10T02:14:00.000Z  00:04:56:CD:7D:17
```

**EDIT**
So I can process the data like this (The values are just for sample, please dont co-relate with the timestamp in actual data)

`[100, 200, 300, 500]`

I want to get mean of all `n+1 - n` where n would range from `0 to len(<list-2)`

I could get it done by creating one more intermediate list

`[100, 100, 200]` and then apply mean. 
Is it the way Or there is a better way of doing it

Comment: Do you want to have the mean time between all possible pairs of entries, or between consecutive entries?

Comment: Consecutive entries

Comment: And what is the `dtype` of your `Polling Timestamp` column?

Comment: Well I'll convert it the datetime and when we take a delta if would come as float I think, for about example it should be 5.0

Comment: So you know how to get a proper difference of consecutive entries? What is the difficulty in getting the mean then? Can't you simply do a slice operation and take the mean of the resulting `Series`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127876/discussion-between-jotasi-and-saurabh-baid).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

# Initializing values
datetimeList = []
datetimeList.append(datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-11-10T02:04:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
datetimeList.append(datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-11-10T02:09:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
datetimeList.append(datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-11-10T02:14:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
datetimeList.append(datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-11-10T02:16:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
datetimeList.append(datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-11-10T02:20:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
datetimeList.append(datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-11-10T02:30:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
datetimeList.append(datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-11-10T03:16:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
datetimeList.append(datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-11-10T03:20:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
datetimeList.append(datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-11-10T03:30:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))

timeDiff = 0
for i1,i2 in zip( np.arange(0,len(datetimeList)-1), np.arange(1,len(datetimeList)) ):
    # minutes get converted to seconds for datetime.timedelta
    # Add time differences (which are in seconds)
    timeDiff += (datetimeList[i2] - datetimeList[i1]).seconds

# Taking average
timeDiff = timeDiff/(len(datetimeList)-1)
```

Output in seconds:

```
In []: timeDiff
Out[]: 645
```